# Best practices to mount Rails engine to several apps on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, rails-engines

I'm a little bit confused about organizing Rails applications and mountable engine in production.

I have N apps, which are using 1 mountable engine (it sets some cookies for apps).
In development it works this way.
Folders:

```
|— app1
|— app2
|— my_engine
```

In apps Gemfile:

```
gem 'my_engine', path: "../my_engine"
```

So all of the apps are mounting it from 1 source.
And I'd like to keep this logic in production.

On my vps apps organized this way (using Capistrano for deploy):

```
|—apps_folder
|— — app1
|— — — current (sym link)
|— — — releases
|— — — shared

|— — app2
|— — — current (sym link)
|— — — releases
|— — — shared

|— git
|— — app1.git
|— — app2.git
```

Can you describe me workflow: how to deploy my_engine to my production and connect it to all of the apps on the server. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean how to deploy the shared rails engine? If the shared the engine is mounted in each rails app, there is no need to deploy the engine alone. After deploy rails app to the production, running `bundle install` will install all the apps dependency, including the shared engine. This is what we did in our deployment.

Comment: So I need to push engine's repo to server and locate it in Gemfiles: `user@server:path/to/engine.git` and `bundle install`. That's right?

Comment: You can push the engine to github and pointing to github in Gemfile.

Comment: Or if not using github, you can upload the engine to server subdir and pointing to it in app's Gemfile.